# Common way to add SDK to VC++?

Tags: visual-c++, sdk

It's the first time that I want to use a downloaded SDK. What is the best way to include its source files, by not adding them to the project folder (external)?

(I'm using VC++ 6.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You just need to set up your compiler and linker include paths to reference the new headers and libraries that are included in the SDK.

For VC6, right click on your project in the Workspace -> `Settings`:

> C/C++ -> Category 'Preprocessor' ->
>   Additional include directories
>
> Link-> Category 'Input' -> Additional
>   library path

For later versions - right click on your project in the Solution Explorer - open `Properties`.

> Configuration Properties-> C/C++ ->
>   General -> Additional Include
>   Directories
>
> Configuration Properties-> Linker ->
>   General -> Additional Library
>   Directories